# RootViewController need to resort/reload data array xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, architecture, ios4, reload

I'm implementing an example, in that example, I read in data from a database, put it in an array, sort it, and it's displayed using the RootViewController.  The DB read and array load happen before the RVC code.  So, it works, I get the data in the window created by the RVC and there's a nav controller there as well.

I want to add a button or something to the nav controller so that when you hit it, it sends a value back to the RootViewController.m file, then based on that value, I want to resort the array and display it once again in the RootViewController window.

I'm not sure how to do this.  What changes would I have to make to the .xib and the RootViewController.m file?

Please, I'm a confused nube.  %-0  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fair amount to this, so I'll give some general points and if any of them cause problems, it may be easier to work out smaller details.

In you RVC's viewDidLoad method, you can create a button and set it as the right or left button in your controller's navigationItem.

You can associate a tap on that button with a method in your controller that can do whatever you want when the button is tapped.  (But a button doesn't send values, really, so you may have to explain more about that idea.)

I assume the RVC has a table view if you're showing array contents, so once the array (mutable array, I'd assume) is re-sorted, you can tell the table view to reload its data.

Comment: Thanks.  I can use more than one button/tab whatever... They're going to be column names you can sort by, so they don't necessarily have to SEND a value as long as I can distinguish between them.  Thanks!  As far as the table view is concerned, it's not in the xib, it's created programatically in the RVC, so it shows the rows, tap on a row, it shows the detail, it works, despite my mangling the code to make it do my bidding.  So assuming I get the array sorted based on an action from the RVC window, HOW, exactly to I tell the table view to reload it's data?

Comment: What I've done (and it's not working but I need to understand why) is to drag a button bar button onto the footer section of the nav controller in the IB.  I've connected it's action to the file owner which is RVC.  There's a synthesize bButton1; in the implementation  and an action - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"howdy doody");
}
.  In the interface: property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *bButton1;   When I press the button, it quits and in the log I see:  -[UIApplication buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: The error says that you connected the button's action to the UIApplication object rather than RVC.  I don't know why that is but double-check the identity that's set for File's Owner.

Comment: Phillip,  I just indicated that your answer was helpful, unfortunately I lack the reputation to do anything else but express my gratitude.  So  THANK YOU VERY MUCH, sir.  I do appreciate your input and it was very helpful.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your secondary question, once you have resorted your array (or generally updated your data however you wish) you can force the table view to reload programmatically

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Where 'tableView' is your instance variable pointing to your table view

Comment: Thanks.  I *THINK* I did this by saying [self.tableView reloadData].  But I'm not sure, I put some NSLog stmts in and it doesn't re-execute viewDidLoad...   would a reloadData cause viewDidLoad to be re-executed?  I DO know that it's getting to the button's action routine because of a log statement, but when it tries to reloadData right after that stmt, it doesn't seem to happen.   PLEASE advise.  Thanks in advance.  And happy Easter.

Comment: No, reloadData only causes the tableView data source to be updated.  if you want to see this happen, you can place an NSLog statement or break inside of:
**- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

This will NOT cause viewDidLoad to re-execute.

Comment: Piwacket, just a friendly note.  Phillip and I have both provided help for you.  It is appropriate that you mark an answer correct and potentially 'upvote' them as well.

Comment: THANKS for the reminder... I totally meant to do that.  and REALLY APPRECIATE both your help.   I've indicated that both answers were helpful.  I don't know how to indicate which one was right, per se (they both are, actually)  I am unable to vote anything up since I lack the reputation.  Anyway, please MobileVet, let me know if there is ANYTHING else I can do to indicate my appreciation.  And thanks again for the reminder.

Comment: No worries, I forgot that it takes 15 rep to upvote...  That being said, you can 'accept' Phillip's answer by checking the check mark below the up / down vote icon on the upper left corner of the answer. (it will turn green) That will give you some rep too. :)  I would accept his, mine was more an add on and maybe you can up vote it later when you have rep.

Comment: Thanks!  I see that I should ask multi-part questions in separate postings.  Thank you very much...  I'm having some other problems that I am going to post today.  I would be MOST APPRECIATIVE, MobileVet, if you would respond, since your input was also correct but I can only hit the checkmark for one of the answers.  Cheers, friend, I totally appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Always happy to take a look when they are posted.

Comment: well, if you don't see it... here's the link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309541/sigabrt-on-filteredarrayusingpredicate