# sigabrt on filteredArrayUsingPredicate

Tags: xcode, predicate, sigabrt

I'm a noob and trying to convert an example from a book into an app I can use.

The sample app is a modified version of the contacts application and it works.

I've done some further modification, and the search no longer works.  It sigabrts on the following line

```
self.filteredAnswercards = [flattenedArray
                            filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I'm stumped.
my head is bloody from beating it against my keyboard.

ANY help is massively appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: would need to see more code..

Comment: I suggest wrapping the line that crashes inside a @try/@catch block and, inside the catch, logging the exception and the result of the exception's `callStackSymbols` method.

Comment: @PhillipMills omg, I did what you suggested and prior to the entire stack dump I got this message:  Catchpoint 3 (exception thrown).2012-04-25 19:52:02.267 Catalog[3862:207] Uncaught exception: [<Answercard 0x68524c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ans_cards_title.  Wow!  That's great because THAT'S the field I'm doing the filtering on.  So, what the heck does that mean?

Comment: @PhillipMills  HOLY CRAP!!!  THANK YOU Phillip!   I was able to see something that I would have THOUGHT would have given me a better error.  The problem was with the predicate, I spelled the field name incorrectly.  In the predicate it was ans_cards_title  but the real name is ans_card_title  (not plural on the card)  oh this was painful!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!    ACTUALLY THANK YOU ALL!!!  I appreciate your time and attention and WOW you've saved me.  Onward boldly I go... to the next exception!!!  :) It's nice to know I'm merely ignorant and NOT crazy  (well, not much)  :)

Comment: @PhillipMills I don't see how to give you credit for this answer... help me give you credit.  Everyone was helpful but this was the one that woke me up... if you answer below... I Think I could give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion was to wrap the line that crashes inside a @try/@catch block and, inside the catch, log the exception and the result of the exception's callStackSymbols method.

For the record, part of the problem with the 4.x versions of Xcode is that they are much worse than 3.x versions at telling you **where** an exception is coming from.  For this reason, getting familiar with tricks that make a program or the debugger tell you what you need to know is very important.

Comment: Phillip,  I joke with my friends that everything I need to know about a language usually ends up being in the first 32 pages of a book!  But it's not really a joke.  It's my hack-as-hack-can approach to learning a new language.  What makes this doubly difficult is that I've avoided using IDEs until now (textpad and vi are my tools of choice) but my caveman debugging is not helping me here.  Your suggestion was great and led me to discover my problem and understand it... AND I'll never develop anything in xcode without this wrapper... so handy it should be generated automagically IMHO.

Comment: ... sorry... still don't have the reputation to vote up a solution, but every one should vote this one up because it worked to help me solve my own problem.  excellent, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to say without seeing more code.  Sigabort generally means an exception has been thrown.  You can put a break point in `objc_exception_throw`to get a back trace which should help highlight the cause.

If you get NO new info with the above, others have said that a full reboot of the computer can help... but I have not had a situation where I could verify this.

---- edit based on comments -----

It sounds like `filteredAnswercards` is nil, that will definitely cause a Sigabort.  Allocate that array properly and you should be good to go.

Comment: I found where to add a breakpoint, I am able to add an exception breakpoint but not I don't know how to be specific about making it on objc_exception_throw, per se.  I've made an exception break point and it's breaking there now, but I don't know WHAT to look at or where to access the value I'd need.  The array involve that's populated is, populated with objects, the receiving array is (null) which is a little troubling since that's the only difference I'm able to glean from the sample code that works (the working sample shows the receiving array as an empty one, not null).

Comment: In my RootViewController.h I have the following 2 lines:
NSArray *filteredAnswercards;     
and
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *filteredAnswercards;
  
and in RootViewController.m I have :  
      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"ans_cards_title beginswith[c] %@", self.searchBar.text];
 
 and
 
     self.filteredAnswercards = [flattenedArray
                                filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

and in the log the predicate is :
ans_cards_title BEGINSWITH[c] "N"

the flattened array has objects in it.

Comment: There is your problem.  The array should not be nil and is producing the sigabort.  Check the docs, notice that filterArrayUsingPredicate does not return an array... it needs to be allocated first.

Comment: actually, now that I'm spilling more info in the log, both versions (working and non-working) have a null array prior to that "filteredArrayUsingPredicate" line.  There is no alloc statement for that array in either version. Unless I'm missing something (which is absolutely the case).  Is there anything I can post that will give you more information?

Comment: The predicate is not null, it's: ans_cards_title BEGINSWITH[c] "n" AND upon better inspection in BOTH versions the receiving array starts out as (null), I must have mis-read the log before. Also, in neither version is any alloc done on the array, they are both defined in RootViewController.h as follows: NSArray *filteredAnswercards; ' and @property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *filteredAnswercards; ` and then they are synthesized in RootViewController.m as follows: `@synthesize filteredAnswercards;' I've searched both and the refs to it are the same

Comment: Update:  I did a stack trace and got the following message:   Catchpoint 3 (exception thrown).2012-04-25 19:52:02.267 Catalog[3862:207] Uncaught exception: [<Answercard 0x68524c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ans_cards_title.   And ans_cards_title is the field I'm filtering on.  Still don't know what that means... off to surf.  All help is still massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `predicate` is nil.  Where did you assign it? Or did you never assign it?

Comment: The predicate is not null, it's: `ans_cards_title BEGINSWITH[c] "n"` (without the single quotes, of course)  AND upon better inspection in BOTH versions the receiving array starts out as (null), I must have mis-read the log before.  Also, in neither version is any alloc done on the array, they are both defined in RootViewController.h as follows:  `NSArray *filteredAnswercards;
' and `@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *filteredAnswercards;
` and then they are synthesized in RootViewController.m as follows: `@synthesize filteredAnswercards;'
I've searched both and the refs to it are the same

Comment: Thank you Ken, I found the error (see above!)  Thanks so much though.  This is the BEST WEBSITE EVER!!!  LOVE you guys!!!